# Electron autoUpdater Error: Update check failed. The server sent an invalid JSON response

Tags: node.js, electron, auto-update, vercel, squirrel

I am implementing `auto update` feature for my `Electron` app. I am encountering an error:

```
[Error: Update check failed. The server sent an invalid response. Try again later.] {
  code: 6,
  domain: 'SQRLUpdaterErrorDomain'
}
```

This error is thrown from inside `Electron` node module, specifically from `Squirrel.framework`:

```
Binary file ./dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Squirrel.framework/Versions/A/Squirrel
```

Part of my `electron` `main.js` code:

```js
    const { app, autoUpdater } = require('electron');

    let version  = app.getVersion();
    let server   = 'https://colube-deploy-pnjad1iun-wenwu.vercel.app';
    //let url    = `${server}/update/${process.platform}/${app.getVersion()}`;
    let platform = process.platform + '_arm64';
    let url      = `${server}/update/${platform}/${version}`;

    autoUpdater.setFeedURL({ url });

    setInterval(() => {
        autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();
    }, 15 * 60 * 1000);

    setTimeout(() => {
        autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();
    }, 3000);

    autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', (event, releaseNotes, releaseName) => {

releaseName, releaseNotes);

        const dialogOpts = {
            type    : 'info',
            buttons : ['Restart', 'Later'],
            title   : 'Application Update',
            message : process.platform === 'win32' ? releaseNotes : releaseName,
            detail  : 'A new version has been downloaded. Restart the application to apply the updates.',
        }

        dialog.showMessageBox(dialogOpts).then((returnValue) => {
            if (returnValue.response === 0) autoUpdater.quitAndInstall();
        })
    });

    autoUpdater.on('before-quit-for-update', () => {
    });

    autoUpdater.on('error', (message) => {
        console.error('There was a problem updating the application.');
        console.error(message);
    });
```

Some background information:

- I am testing on `M2-chip MacOS Monterey 12.4`. `Electron` version is `^19.0.8`
- I am using `autoUpdater` from `electron` module
- I am using [Hazel](https://github.com/vercel/hazel) which is recommended in [Electron official document](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/updates#step-1-deploying-an-update-server).
- Hazel is deployed to [Vercel](https://vercel.com/).
- App releases are behind a private `github` repo.
- App releases are notarized by Apple successfully.
- Hazel server is configured with environment variable `TOKEN` (my github personal token).
- The `url` argument passed to `setFeedURL()` is `https://colube-deploy-pnjad1iun-wenwu.vercel.app/update/darwin_arm64/0.9.13`
- Vercel server response to request `autoUpdater.checkForUpdates()` is status code `200` with `object` like:

```js
{
    name: 'v0.9.17',
    notes: '',
    pub_date: '2022-07-31T13:47:34Z',
    url: 'colube-deploy-pnjad1iun-wenwu.vercel.app/download/darwin_arm64?update=true'
}
```

- Paste above response url `colube-deploy-pnjad1iun-wenwu.vercel.app/download/darwin_arm64?update=true` to browser can successfully download the app.

Comment: Any update on this? I am struggling with the same issue

Comment: @PeterMaher I changed my private app release repository to public, now I use Electron's officially recommended auto-update service "update.electronjs.org", auto-update works fine now.

Comment: @PeterMaher did you find a way to overcome this issue without changing your repo to public like suggested above?